# LinkButton not firing  PostBack with image and ImageMap associated with it

Tags: asp.net, html, imagemap

I'm having one hell of a time trying to figure out why I can't get the `LinkButton` to PostBack when I have an image with an `ImageMap` associated with it.

Let me describe the system a little, so you can get a basic understanding of what's happening. The `LinkButton` has `onClick` set to call `window.shoModalDialog`, which obviously opens a modal window where the user can select various options an an ImageMap, save, and close the window. When the window closes, a PostBack is supposed to occur so that the main landing page gets updated with the new options selected.

To add complexity, the link button needs to have an image that shows what points were selected in modal window (the image is a smaller version of the previous window). So what I've done is add an image map to the image in the LinkButton like so:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlC2R1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">
        <img ID="SomeImage" alt="Some image" 
              runat="server" src="~/Images/SomeImage.jpg" usemap="#SomeMap" />
     </asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

The map is a regular HTML map (not the ASP.NET one, though I'm sure it's rendered the same, but I digress). Also, I'm using [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) to highlight the points that have been selected, but that doesn't cause any issues as far as I can tell.

If I remove the `usemap` attribute, a PostBack occurs, if I add it back in, it doesn't.

Is the ImageMap overriding the events that are supposed to occur under normal conditions for the LinkButton? Is there a way to make the ImageMap do a PostBack like the `LinkButton' would under normal circustances?

I tried using the ASP.NET `ImageButton` control, but I couldn't figure out how to get the ImageMap on it, if that's even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I need to clarify anything, I'm fairly certain half of what I wrote probably doesn't make sense. :D

**UPDATE**
The issue had nothing to do with the `ImageMap` itself. It had to do with the `OnClientClick` closing the modal dialog before the `OnClick` event could be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use the asp:ImageMap instead

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap.aspx